# How to recursively dive through deeply nested typescript models? And map those deep paths as an object [key: value]

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I've a challenge.

How to recursively dive through deeply nested typescript models? And map those deep paths as an object [key: value].

where key - is the column name or an identifiable name & value is the path (depth ) traversed.

what I mean by depth is this someObject.level1.level2.level3.level4... Like that.

Imagine I have a couple of Typescript Interfaces (all external files).

One Interface Pointing to another then the other & so On.

Eg:

```
export interface University {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  locationDetails: Location;
  revenue: Revenue;
  departments: Departments[];
  collegesUnder: Colleges[];
  status: boolean;
}
```

Here is the interface describing Location

```
export interface Location {
  street: string;
  state: string;
  postCode: number;
}
```

Here is the interface describing a Department

```
export interface Departments {
  name: string;
  category: string;
  coursesOffered: Courses[];
}
```

Here is the interface describing a College

```
export interface College {
  collegeName: string;
  collegeLocation: Location;
  coursesOffered: Courses[];
  studentsEnrolled: Students[];
}
```

Here is the interface describing a Student

```
export interface Student {
  studentName: string;
  department: Department;
  course: Course;
  age: number;
  address: string;
  otherInfo: OtherInfo;
}
```

Here is the interface describing a Course

```
export interface Course {
  name: string;
  classifiedUnder: string;
  subCourses: Course[];
}
```

So as you can there are a bunch of typescript files. All of them are separate files & are named by the convention interfaceName.model.ts.
interfaceName corresponds to each Interface Identifier Name.
The frontent is being developed using Angular.

I will be getting json data from a server which contains the infos of universities.
& all these datas will be shown as a table(without any nesting).

On top of each headers I will have an input field & as the use types in the table filters out.

In order to search deeply I will have to access the deeply nested paths of these models.
And I will have to do that separately for each type of search requests.

& whenever some property is added newly in any of these interfaces, I will have to come & make changes accordingly.

So I come up with a solution:

to map each column name with the depth of the object:

For example if the user searches in the column of Student Name:

```
return universities.filter(university => {
retrurn university.colleges.some(college => {
return college.students.some(student => {
return student.name
})
})
})
```

So my idea is to map each column name with each depths so that I can access it directly:

like this:

```
searchMap = {
universityName: university.name,
universityType: university.type;
universityLocationStreet: university.location.street;
universityLocationState: university.location.state;
universityLocationPostcode: university.location.postcode;

... Like so...

studentsName: university[i].colleges[j].students[k].student.name
// see how the nesting goes on... 
}
```

So the point is that if any changes occur in the typescript.model.ts files (in future if they make any changes to the properties)
I want to manage it automatically.

So I want to find a solution to recursively crawl through these typescript interfaces (which are all external & will be imported inside the type definitions) & make a searchMap (depth map) object out of it.

Comment: One of the issues with the question title is that I don't think this is recursion. Aside from that though: is this more of a hypothetical question? It's a strange design for anything, and if I saw this approach in a real-life application it would be a bit of a red flag.

Comment: This sounds like you want code generation using something like [ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/tree/latest/packages/ts-morph) or writing your own. It's not something you're going to get for free from TS or JS.

Comment: add more data, even code seems broken. Add data

Comment: This is not hypothetical. The idea is to have an automatic object depth map.

Comment: This is recursion. Because when it finds another type definition(which is again another object), the code will have to do the same procedure to dive deep to that new object

& then append all these depths as follows:

Object.depth1.depth2.depth3.depth4 etc...

Comment: Normally you wouldn't use a hierarchical arrangement for this.  Students aren't a subset of a university; universities simply have students.  Making it hierarchical enormously complicates storage and retrieval, as you've already seen.

Comment: It is not a strange idea. You can find similarities with the vscode or your IDE intellisense. & we type in each depths (for defined interfaces) we can access these depth properties. What I here want is just to trace these paths automatically & concat them together & then map those to an object with an idetifiable keyword, so that when ever I need to access these depths/levels I just have to put that key on the object.

Comment: That's different.  Code in a compiler is arranged into hierarchical structures called "abstract  syntax trees."  Code is unavoidably, relentlessly hierarchical.  Relationships between entities are generally not.

Comment: No not to do anything with the compiler.

Just trace these depths/paths & map them to an object.

Can we find a way to do that?

Comment: Students are subsets of Departments | Departments are subsets of Colleges | Colleges are subsets of Universities.

Comment: No.  Students are *members* of departments.

Comment: Anyway, mapping anything to a HashTable or Dictionary is easy enough.  Do some research on Tree Traversal and the Visitor Pattern.

Comment: Mapping an object means creating an object with the key as the column name & value as the path to access it. So imagine if i want to access Students Name.

I will have to do it like this.

university[i].colleges[j].students[k].student.name

So if mapped as an object.

{..., studentName: university[i].colleges[j].students[k].student.name}.

So this object contains lots of other maps like the one above.

Comment: Yes, I get it.  You want a Dictionary.  Something like [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/building-type-safe-dictionaries-in-typescript-a072d750cbdf).

Comment: How to create is "learn about Tree Traversal."

Comment: You might be able to use something from https://github.com/bangbang93/apidoc-plugin-ts