# Achieving delay for custom observable types

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable of numbers which is delayed by 1 sec.

```
const obsNums = from([...Array(100).keys()])
obsNums.pipe(delayWhen((x: number) => timer(x * 1000))).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

can we achieve something similar with custom types?

```
const obsCus = from(this.item$ = this.getItems())
```

```
  getItems(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<Observable<any>>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  }
```

```
obsCus.pipe(delayWhen((usr: user) => timer(usr * 1000))).subscribe(usr => console.log(usr))
```

The idea here is to delay users by one sec just like numbers array.

Comment: use of `rxjs interval` it should be worked.

Comment: can you show how?

Answer (score 0):

Use `concatMap` to feed the user to the stream with a one sec delay

```
getItems().pipe(
switchMap(users=>from(users))
concatMap(user=>timer(1000).pipe(mapTo(user)))
)
```

Comment: Great. Thank You. It is working.
Thanks a lot, Man.

Comment: Yep. Sure. I'm using it. Is there any way to contact you in the future? If I have similar problems with angular/rxjs.

Comment: Will leave some contact info in my profile soon. I spend most my time here to support rxjs question, u will see me from time to time

Comment: Ok. Great. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Fan Cheung, I need one more help man. Can you please send your suggestions on this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60868988/how-to-recursively-dive-through-deeply-nested-typescript-models-and-map-those-d

Comment: So the idea above is to create an object that contains all the paths of an api.

For example if I want to search for a particular item(Mangoes) which is deeply nested I will just put the item on my object so that I can access the path.

ObjectMap[Mangoes] = Object.depth1.depth2.depth3.depth4.Mangoes